# Call method whenever method in other class is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, oop, events

In given two classes:

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) { 
    this.name = name; 
  }

  feedCats() {
    console.log(this.name + ' fed the cats');
  }
}
```

and:

```
class Cat {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  meow() {
    console.log(this.name + ' says \'meow\'');
  }
}
```

**I want method `meow()` in every `Cat`'s instance to be called whenever any instance of `Person` is calling `feedCats()` method. How can I do this?**

I assume maybe the events handling will be needed, however in JavaScript `event` type is needed when using `addEventListener()` method and I can't find the proper one. I need the fastest JavaScript or jQuery solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that there's a very easy path to solve this problem.

Move `feedCats` to a new class called `CatFeeder`, and add which cats should be fed before `feed` gets called:

```
class CatFeeder extends Person {
    constructor(...args) {
         super(...args);

         this.cats = [];
    }

    addCat(name) {
         this.cats.push(new Cat(name));
    }

    feed() {
         this.cats.forEach(cat => cat.meow());

         console.log(`${this.name} fed the cats and they said meow!`);
    }
}


var catFeeder = new CatFeeder("Matías");
catFeeder.addCat("Inno");
catFeeder.addCat("Darky");

catFeeder.feed();
```

At the end of the day, a `Person` isn't a *cat feeder* per se, but is a `CatFeeder` (who's a person, but not any person). For me, this feels more natural than considerating that any person has the properties and behaviors to feed a cat.